# Angular JS regarding populating dynamic row data in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Please see this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpGhO.png)I need some help. I want to populate dynamic table's row data into a form when i clicked on the particular row.When i try this html elements are repeating along with data when i click on the table rows, but i need like elements should not repeat only data should change. This is my template code

```html
    <table class="table2">
<tr>
    <th>'Player'</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat=" usr in fc.saveData" ng-click="fc.fnRowClick(usr)">
  <td>{{usr.player}}</td><td>{{usr.age}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div ng-repeat="data in fc.displayData track by $index">
<label for="field1">
<span>Name</span><input type="text" name="field1" required="true" ng-model="data.player"/>
</label>
<label for="field2">
<span>Age</span><input type="text" name="field2" required="true" ng-model="data.age"/>
</label>

</div>
```

This is my js code.

```js
fc.displayData=[];
fc.fnRowClick = function(usr){
  console.log(usr);
  fc.displayData.push(usr);
  console.log(fc.displayData);`
 }
```

Comment: Needing a solution usually implies solving a problem. You have not identified a problem. Suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You haven't specified data - `fc.saveData`.

Comment: you have duplicate name attribute. screenshot proves this.

Comment: That is the problem, when i click on the row, the row data should populate in the textbox and when i click on the next row the data should change but the textbox should not repeat but it is repeating

Answer (score 0):

html **name** attribute is beeing duplicated during ng-repeat. 
That may cause this problem. 
Change:

```
<label for="field1">
<span>Name</span><input type="text" name="field1" required="true" ng-model="data.player"/>
</label>
```

to this:

```
<label for="field1{{$index}}">
<span>Name</span><input type="text" name="field1{{$index}}" required="true" ng-model="data.player"/>
</label>
```

Do the same for second label.

Comment: Sorry it is not working. Pleas have a look into the screenshot i have attached in the beginning of my post